# Looping a object item and compare

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to compare var and var b and if b is available in a i need to append 1 in the a and if it was false I need to add 0

```
 var a=[["AED",1],["AFN",22.08086],["ALL",27.171554],["AMD",105.058803], ["ANG",0.487406],["AOA",227.493716],["ARS",95.308373],["AUD",0.420237],["AWG",0.487406], ["AZN",0.462914],["BAM",0.490727],["BBD",0.544588]];

var b=[AED,AFN,AMD]
```

compare a and b and if b code exist in a need to append 1 in the array

OUTPUT

```
   [["AED",1,1],["AFN",22.08086,1],["ALL",27.171554,0],["AMD",105.058803,1] ["ANG",0.487406,0],["AOA",227.493716,0],["ARS",95.308373,0],["AUD",0.420237,0],["AWG",0.487406,0],["AZN",0.462914,0],["BAM",0.490727,0],["BBD",0.544588,0]]
```

Comment: You can loop through the list a and check if first element of inner list is present in list b by using b.includes() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop that checks if `b` [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) an item in `a` will do the trick. This mutates the original array.

```js
var a = [
  ["AED", 1],
  ["AFN", 22.08086],
  ["ALL", 27.171554],
  ["AMD", 105.058803],
  ["ANG", 0.487406],
  ["AOA", 227.493716],
  ["ARS", 95.308373],
  ["AUD", 0.420237],
  ["AWG", 0.487406],
  ["AZN", 0.462914],
  ["BAM", 0.490727],
  ["BBD", 0.544588]
];
var b = ["AED", "AFN", "AMD"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  b.includes(a[i][0]) ? a[i].push(1) : a[i].push(0);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: is it possible to sort by 3 rd key  [["AED",1,1],
    ["AFN",22.08086,1],
    ["ALL",27.171554,0],
    ["AMD",105.058803,1], 
    ["ANG",0.487406,0],
    ["AOA",227.493716,0]]

1 come first then only all 0 s

Comment: Sure `.sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2]);`

Comment: Tuple type '[string, unknown]' of length '2' has no element.. getting this error

Answer (score 3):

You can use `+` to coerce true/false into 1/0. This approach uses destructuring to extract the first element as `i` and the remaining elements as `j`.

```js
const a = [['AED',1],['AFN',22.08086],['ALL',27.171554],['AMD',105.058803], ['ANG',0.487406],['AOA',227.493716],['ARS',95.308373],['AUD',0.420237],['AWG',0.487406], ['AZN',0.462914],['BAM',0.490727],['BBD',0.544588]];

const b = ['AED','AFN','AMD']

const out = a.map(([i, ...j]) => [i, ...j, +b.includes(i)])

console.log(out)
```

or, to alter the original array directly:

```js
const a = [['AED',1],['AFN',22.08086],['ALL',27.171554],['AMD',105.058803], ['ANG',0.487406],['AOA',227.493716],['ARS',95.308373],['AUD',0.420237],['AWG',0.487406], ['AZN',0.462914],['BAM',0.490727],['BBD',0.544588]];

const b = ['AED','AFN','AMD']

a.forEach(i => i.push(+b.includes(i[0])))

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [["AED",1],["AFN",22.08086],["ALL",27.171554],["AMD",105.058803], ["ANG",0.487406],["AOA",227.493716],["ARS",95.308373],["AUD",0.420237],["AWG",0.487406], ["AZN",0.462914],["BAM",0.490727],["BBD",0.544588]];
var b = ["AED", "AFN", "AMD"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (b.includes(a[i][0])) {
    a[i].push(1);
  } else {
    a[i].push(0);
  }
}

console.log(a);
```

This code snippet will iterate through each sub-array in a, check if the currency code (first element) exists in the array b, and then push either 1 or 0 to the sub-array accordingly. The resulting array a will have the desired output as you've mentioned.